# MVVM AsyncCommand NullReference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

Some time ago i decided to study MVVM and async/await.
With entity framework code-first my application can write new users to database.
At [MSDN async databinding article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) i got for for test async binding class NotifyTaskCompletion.cs (was renamed to TaskPropertyWatcher.cs) for async loading users from database. This class working.
After that [second article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) was read.
I copy-paste full async class from article, bind AsyncCommand to button.

Problem: Have NullReferenceException when binded Button was clicked.
This is not a compiler error.
Maybe someone can help with this "magic"?

AsyncCommandBase class error debug info:

[image]

AsyncCommand  class error debug info:
[image]

[Example solution from MSDN(first item at page)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/msdnmag0414) working perfecty...

My DAL AddUser method:

```
   public static async Task AddUser(User usr)
    {
        using (var cntx = new ServiceDBContext())
        {
            cntx.Users.Add(usr);
            await cntx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Entity model:

```
 [Table("Users")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string ClientType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }

  }
```

My ViewModel part:

```
   public CustomerAddViewModel()
    {
       AddClient = AsyncCommand.Create(() => DAL.DbService.AddUser(Client));
    }
    private User _user = new User();
    public User Client
    {
        get
        {
            return _user;
        }
        set {
            _user = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

View constructor:

```
    public CustomerAddView()
    {

        DataContext = new CustomerAddViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

My View databinding part:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddClient}" x:Name="button" Content="Add user" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" Height="26"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Client.ClientName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Client.ClientType}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Client.EMail}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Client.Phone}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" ></TextBox>
```

MSDN code:

```
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}
public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);

    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
public class AsyncCommand<TResult> : AsyncCommandBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> _command;
    private readonly CancelAsyncCommand _cancelCommand;
    private TaskPropertyWatcher <TResult> _execution;

    public AsyncCommand(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> command)
    {
        _command = command;
        _cancelCommand = new CancelAsyncCommand();
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return Execution == null || Execution.IsCompleted;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        _cancelCommand.NotifyCommandStarting();
        Execution = new TaskPropertyWatcher<TResult>(_command(_cancelCommand.Token));
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        await Execution.TaskCompletion;
        _cancelCommand.NotifyCommandFinished();
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
        get { return _cancelCommand; }
    }

    public TaskPropertyWatcher<TResult> Execution
    {
        get { return _execution; }
        private set
        {
            _execution = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private sealed class CancelAsyncCommand : ICommand
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private bool _commandExecuting;

        public CancellationToken Token { get { return _cts.Token; } }

        public void NotifyCommandStarting()
        {
            _commandExecuting = true;
            if (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public void NotifyCommandFinished()
        {
            _commandExecuting = false;
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _commandExecuting && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested;
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        private void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }
}

public static class AsyncCommand
{
    public static AsyncCommand<object> Create(Func<Task> command)
    {
        return new AsyncCommand<object>(async _ => { await command(); return null; });
    }

    public static AsyncCommand<TResult> Create<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> command)
    {
        return new AsyncCommand<TResult>(_ => command());
    }

    public static AsyncCommand<object> Create(Func<CancellationToken, Task> command)
    {
        return new AsyncCommand<object>(async token => { await command(token); return null; });
    }

    public static AsyncCommand<TResult> Create<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> command)
    {
        return new AsyncCommand<TResult>(command);
    }
}
```

P.S Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException` because `TaskCompletion` is `null`.

There was a bug in the original code download for the second (async commands) article, where `NotifyTaskCompletion` will have a null `TaskCompletion` if the task is completed before the `NotifyTaskCompletion` is constructed.

This bug did not exist in the first article (which did not have any `TaskCompletion` at all), and was fixed a while ago for the second article. I recommend you re-download it.

Comment: Thanks!
But i use another way in AsyncCommand...
          await Execution.Task;
            _cancelCommand.NotifyCommandFinished();
I tested it in different ways and its works! 
Property style is working, in AsynCommand awaiting Task property working too.
P.S You articles are perfect! Thank you.

Comment: P.S using NotifyTaskCompletion from first article with await Execution.Task

Comment: @user1576474: There's one big difference between awaiting `Task` and `TaskCompletion`: in the case of errors, awaiting `Task` will re-raise the task's exception, crashing the app instead of allowing `NotifyTaskCompletion` to handle the error via data binding.